# Running the android in-app billing example aplication

Tags: android, in-app-billing

This will probably sound silly but I have no idea how to make the application work.

[tutorial for in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download)

Just like the tutorial says I downloaded the package, I found the files. The problem is there's no project file and I can't get it to work in eclipse.

Anyone used the example app?

Answer (score 2):

I've used it successfully...what seems to be the problem?  Once you download the files, bring the project into Eclipse by select "Newn Android Project", "Create project form existing source" and the "Finish."  From there, follow the directions regarding changing the package name, etc...

Comment: Usually the samples are built by going "New Android Project -> Create project from existing sample" and then selecting an API level.  The missing project file would prevent this, but creating from existing source should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can determine, the sample Dungeons in-app billing project that I downloaded via Android SDK Manager, does not even compile (this seems to have been fixed, see my comments later in this message..).

As a check, I ran a find command to search for one of the missing resources:

```
 /cygdrive/k/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/play_billing $ find . -name '*.xml' -exec grep edit_payload_title {} \; -print

        android:text="@string/edit_payload_title" />
   ./res/layout/edit_payload.xml

 /cygdrive/k/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/play_billing $
```

As you can see, the resource @string_edit_payload_title is referenced once, but never defined in any of the xml files..

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/screen_background').    item_row.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 20 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/screen_background').    main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 20 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'prompt' with value                 '@string/select_item'). main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 52 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/buy').   main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 47 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/edit_payload_title').    edit_payload.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 25 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/edit_payload').  main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 58 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/items_for_sale').    main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 34 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/items_you_own'). main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 64 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/recent_transactions').   main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 80 Android AAPT Problem
    error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/error_message'). main.xml    /Dungeons/res/layout    line 28 Android AAPT Problem
```

** UPDATE ** I just downloaded it again and it seems to be resolved.  At least, it builds and deploys now..  And the string definitions seem to be in place now..

```
/cygdrive/k/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/play_billing $ find . -name '*.xml' -exec     grep edit_payload_title {} \; -print
        android:text="@string/edit_payload_title" />
./res/layout/edit_payload.xml
    <string name="edit_payload_title">Edit the developer payload associated with this purchase</string>
./res/values/strings.xml
```